# Why are there several keys unbound in vim?

Tags: vim, vi, key-mapping

There are several keys that are unbound in vi/vim, such as `g, q, v and #`. Is there a particular reason why these keys are unbound? Can I just use them however I want or will I be breaking certain conventions concerning their use?

Comment: All those keys are bound in `vim`. `#` is bound in `nvi`.

Answer (score 7):

All listed keys by you are used. You can inspect a key in vim with `:help`:

```
:help <key>
```

for example:

```
:help v
```

or checkout [this vim cheat sheet](http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "Is there a particular reason why these keys are unbound?".

Comment: But these keys **are** bound.